# SharePoint UPS Proxy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I had a situation with UPS service. I have a farm with 2 WFE and 2 AppServers.
In the WFE there are two WebApplication.

From the AppServer of this farms the UPS is connected to the UPS of other Farm.
From the WebApplication there are a proxy configured to consume this UPS Service.
From one of this WebApplication I can see the attribute of Mobile Number from People Pick but from the other not. There is a Application Proxy Group for each WebApp in which the are consuming the same UPS Proxy connection.

I try many things like recreate the Application Proxy Group from powershell or even try the command -SyncFromAD from the cmdlet SET-SPUser.

Anyone had a suggestion of what is going on?

I have a doubt of with service application must be associated with the UPS Proxy, because the Proxy Group I only have the UPS Service.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I just redeploy the WSP solution and did a IISReset, and the Mobile attribute that I wasn't able to see in the People Picker now is showed. 
The problem that I couldn't found the root cause of this. :(
 But now is working again.
Cheers!

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Always do an IISReset!  Especially when establishing new claim providers and using certificates.

http://iedaddy.com/2010/10/sharepoint-2010-connect-to-another-farms-user-profile-service/